# Tag synonym creation rejected even though it has no approved synonyms

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I wanted to make [web-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-console) a tag synonym of [firefox-developer-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-developer-tools), but it was rejected saying that the synonym already exists. The message looked like this:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> A synonym from web-console to firefox-developer-tools exists, chains are not allowed

Though the [page of `firefox-developer-tools` synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firefox-developer-tools/synonyms) says that it doesn't have any approved synonyms.

[image: Synonym creation rejected while there are no approved synonyms]

As it says "no **approved** synonyms", I suspect that somebody already suggested to make [web-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-console) a synonym, which is not approved yet. Though the given info is confusing in this regard.

Is that the case? Or is this a bug? What are users expected to do in this case?

Comment: It's a bit confusing, but what's going on is that `firefox-developer-tools` was proposed as a synonym in Jan 2016 for `firebug`... (you can see this by going to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms and start typing firefox into the filter text area)

Comment: `web-console` should not be a synonym of `firefox-developer-tools`, because the tag wiki mentions its use in Chrome and IE. If it is to be a synonym, the tag wiki should be edited to limit its use to Firefox only (which would be a shame, since we don't seem to have a browser-agnostic tag for the console).

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for the info! It sounds plausible that this may be the reason, though the error message does not indicate that at all. So, if that's really the reaon, the message is incorrect.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If `web-console` should be kept, it's description needs to be adjusted to say that it covers all browser developer tools. Currently, it's first sentence indicates that it's a synonym for the Firefox Developer Tools, even when the next sentences relativate this. Regarding the questions tagged with it, it is mostly used as synonym for the Firefox DevTools, sometimes used for all browser developer tools and often misused for other tools.